# div onmouseover loses when going over other divs inside main div

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I have a `li`,some other elements like `divs`, `inputs` inside this `li`,and everything inside the gridview.

I have a `onmouseover="calcRoute();"` on `li`.

*`PROBLEM`* : I have noticed that on hovering on inside element `divs` and coming out of element divs to the parent `div` causes the `calcRoute();` to execute again ,ie bind google maps again, which causes a flickering due to map rebind.

*`TRIED`* : `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`,but it wont support in all browsers

```html
<li onmouseover="calcRoute(8.4572136,76.94017529999996);return false; ">
  <div class="li-inner">


   <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FESearchListingControl1$dlPhotoView$ctl01$imgPhotoView" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FESearchListingControl1_dlPhotoView_ctl01_imgPhotoView" src="../UploadedImages/House2469-22-8-2012.jpg" style="height:142px;width:219px;border-width:0px;">
   <div class="title">

   <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FESearchListingControl1_dlPhotoView_ctl01_lblPropName" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FESearchListingControl1$dlPhotoView$ctl01$lblPropName','')">Halloween</a>
    <div class="star"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="address">
        <div class="left-location">


        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FESearchListingControl1_dlPhotoView_ctl01_lblDistrict">Trivandrum</span>

        </div>
        <div class="right-price"><span class="WebRupee">Rs</span>
            <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FESearchListingControl1_dlPhotoView_ctl01_lblPrice">500.00</span>
        </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: If you want this event to happen with some elemnts, you should put the onmouseover event to that elements only. But I think that if you put the event on the parent element (the li), every element inside it will shot the calcRoute event. Which one do you want to shot the event?

Comment: @Sonhja I want calcRoute event on the parent li,actualy its not executing on each element hover,its executing each time when mouse returns back to parent li from child elements.

Comment: You could try to determine if the mouse is actually over the element using the mouse coordinates (you get them from the event) and the position and size of the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an id to the li elements and pass this id to the calcRoute function.

```
onmouseover="calcRoute(8.4572136,76.94017529999996, this.id);
```

Then, in this function you can set a flag for this li element that it's been hovered before.

```
var hoveredItems = {}; // this is a global object

function calcRoute(x,y,id) {
 // put this control on top so that recurring operations will be prevented from being run.
 if(hoveredItems[id]) return;
 else hoveredItems[id] = true; 
 ..
}
```

Maybe this helps...

Comment: This I will prefer as Plan B,Is there any HTML,CSS ways to achieve this.